# Up and Downvote button

Tags: javascript, meteor, vote-up-buttons

I try to achieve an up or downvote button where a user is able to vote just 1 time up and 1 time down. If you already have upvoted something it should be possible to remove that with another click on the upvote button, but i dont know what is missing for this. My code looks like the following. I guess i have to implement something with a true of false statement but i tried some things and nothing worked. I would appreciate your help!

```
Template.postArgument.events({
 'click':function() {
  Session.set('selected_argument', this._id);
  },
 'click .yes':function() {
          if(Meteor.user()) {
            var postId = Arguments.findOne({_id:this._id})
            console.log(postId);
            if($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), postId.votedUp) !==-1) {
              return "Voted";
            } else {
        var argumentId = Session.get('selected_argument');
        Arguments.update(argumentId, {$inc: {'score': 1 }}); 
        Arguments.update(argumentId, {$addToSet: {votedUp: Meteor.userId()}});
            }
          }
  }});
```

Comment: This is not syntactically valid... you don't close the `click` event's function with a closing brace. Either you omitted some things during pasting, or else you have some syntax issues to fix before this will do what you expect.

Comment: it was just a failure during the copy and paste ;)

Comment: So, in other words, you want two checkboxes that look like vote buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general approach is correct however you don't need the Session variable at all or even the first click handler. And you don't need to return anything at all from the function.

```
Template.postArgument.events({
  'click .yes': function(){
    if ( Meteor.user() ) {
      var post = Arguments.findOne({_id:this._id});
      if ( $.inArray(Meteor.userId(), post.votedUp) === -1 ) {
        Arguments.update(this._id, {
          $inc: { score: 1 },
          $addToSet: { votedUp: Meteor.userId() }
        }); 
      } else {
        Arguments.update(this._id, {
          $inc: { score: -1 },
          $pull: { votedUp: Meteor.userId() }
        }); 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: but if i click a second time on the .yes button how can i remove my last +1 score?

Answer (score 3):

You can start simple by checking for the existence of the user in the upvotes and downvotes and increment/decrement accordingly then add the user to the sets.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'downvote post': function (postId) {
    check(postId, String);
    let post = Posts.findOne(postId);

    Posts.update(postId, post.downvoters.indexOf(this.userId !== -1) ? {
      $inc: { downvotes: -1 },               // remove this user's downvote.
      $pull: { downvoters: this.userId }     // remove this user from downvoters
    } : {
      $inc: { downvotes: 1 },                // add this user's downvote
      $addToSet: { downvoters: this.userId } // add this user to downvoters.
    });
  }
});
```